# How to compare partial string matches in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I was wondering how one would compare strings for a partial match. For example,

to see if the phrase  "example" is found in a sentence, say "this is an example"?

Comment: Any answer you could accept?

Answer (score 3):

Use `string-contains` from SRFI 13:

```
> (require srfi/13)
> (string-contains "this is an example" "example")
11
> (string-contains "this is an example" "hexample")
#f
```

Answer (score 3):

In Racket the general mechanism for this are [regular expressions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp.html):

```
(regexp-match "example" "this is an example")
=> '("example")

(regexp-match-positions "example" "this is an example")
=> '((11 . 18))
```

Regular expressions are a slightly complex but very powerful way of processing strings. You can specify if the search string needs to be a separate word, search for repetitive patterns or character classes. See the excellent Racket doc for this.